# Why my mouse and keyboard doesn't work once I unplug the charger from my laptop?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, power-management

I have Ubuntu 22.4 on an Asus MA515DA with 8 GB of RAM and a VEGA 8. I bought it a year ago and, as soon as I got home, I installed Ubuntu. Since back then, once I unpluged or pluged the charger, any  peripherals would just stop working, although my monitor doesn´t get affected at all, I can fix it by rebooting it, but it is kind of depressing to lose everything that I'm using.
Just now, a year later, I1m trying to fix it, but nothing works... I think that is some kind of energy economy.
Sorry for any English mistakes and one "salve" from Brasil.

Comment: Sounds like possibly a power issue where you might need to perform a power reset on your system.  If you can, remove all power from your laptop, even the battery (if possible).  Then press and hold down the power switch for 30 seconds.  Reconnect battery and the power supply then power it back on.

Comment: didn't work out, I couldn't take the battery off though...
For me, it's got be a software problem, because it works just fine with the charger pluged.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: You can still hold down the button for 30 seconds.  The only way to know for certain that it is a software problem then is to boot to either a Live CD and test it or a different OS.

Comment: I did hold the button for 30 seconds. I will try to boot on a different OS then... Didn't thought about itkkkk
Thanks man.